# Trouble with the poisson model-integer number

Tags: r, integer, poisson

I'm having trouble with the running of a log-log regression model with Poisson. How should I prevent this warning message? It's also the first time that I use Poisson so I really don't know how to do. Thanks a lot

```
sardegnalog.lm <-glm(log1p(fulldata[381:400,1])~log1p(fulldata[381:400,2])+log1p(fulldata[381:400,3])+log1p(fulldata[381:400,4])+log1p(fulldata[381:400,8]), family="poisson")
Warning messages:
1: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 8.868132
2: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 9.885069
3: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 9.410911 
4: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 7.876259
5: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 11.826326
6: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 9.632728
7: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 9.872616
8: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 6.899723
9: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 9.027379
10: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 16.733528
```

> ```
> summary(sardegnalog.lm)
> ```

```
Call:
glm(formula = log1p(fulldata[381:400, 1]) ~ log1p(fulldata[381:400, 
2]) + log1p(fulldata[381:400, 3]) + log1p(fulldata[381:400, 
4]) + log1p(fulldata[381:400, 8]), family = "poisson")

Deviance Residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-3.267  -2.082  -1.093   1.085   3.123  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 -17.5129     5.2594  -3.330 0.000869 ***
log1p(fulldata[381:400, 2])   1.3144     0.4632   2.838 0.004544 ** 
log1p(fulldata[381:400, 3])   0.7884     0.2384   3.307 0.000944 ***
log1p(fulldata[381:400, 4])  -0.1477     0.2613  -0.565 0.571836    
log1p(fulldata[381:400, 8])  -0.7765     0.2960  -2.623 0.008715 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 144.602  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  80.231  on 15  degrees of freedom
AIC: Inf

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Comment: It is giving you a warning because the Poisson distribution only has support on the non-negative integers.

Comment: So, if I don't have non-negative integers I can't use the Poisson distribution?

Comment: you should explain more of what you're doing (why do you want to use a Poisson regression?).  The question might be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm  trying to do an analysis about the emissions impact that has the freight sector transport in every region in a country

Comment: In general, it is not appropriate: compare `dpois(1,5)` and `dpois(1.01,5)`. The warnings in `glm` come from the attempted computation of the AIC which uses `dpois`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to be certain because you haven't been sufficiently explicit about the model, but it looks like you need to simply drop the `log1p` on the left hand side of the formula; the Poisson glm already has a log link function by default (but you don't need to add 1, because it's the mean, not the data that is transformed to the scale of the linear predictor).

You would still need it on the right though.